# Accidently installed gui on headless 20.04.05 server

Tags: server

I was intending to install gnome-tweaks on my desktop via the command line.  However, I didn't realize is was ssh'd into my headless server when I did so.  Upon realizing my mistake I "sudo apt remove gnome-tweaks" from the server, but discovered I've been left with a barebones gui at startup.  This desktop enviro doesn't even contain "terminal".  How can I remove this gui/destop enviro?  The only thing i've found and tried is:

sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-core

which didn't work.  Please understand I am a beginner, and keep this in mind when responding.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: try `sudo apt autoremove`. If all the GUI stuff was only installed as dependencies of `gnome-tweaks` and you uninstalled `gnome-tweaks`, that's all that should be necessary.

Comment: My bad. forgot to mention I did that too.  Still boots into gui/desktop.

Comment: you can also try looking to see exactly which packages were installed when you installed `gnome-tweaks`, and manually `apt purge` those.

Comment: ...that I'll need help with.  Is there a log somewhere?

Comment: I also noticed via gui/settings lists Wayland as windowing system.  Does this mean anything applicable?

Comment: Wayland is default in 22.04

Comment: The logs are in /var/log/apt. The "history" one may be the most helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!